# Вывод php ошибок на сервере

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, apache2

Перенес свой проект на сервер. Сервер: ubuntu 16.04, apahce2. Залез в php.ini и включил вывод ошибок, то есть заменил `error_reporting`, `display_erros`, `display_startup_erros` 
на `error_reporting = E_ALL`
`display_errors = On`
`display_startup_errors = On`
Но ошибки все равно не показываются. Вот проект: http://185.179.188.59/

Вот что в логах: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас 500 ошибка, это ошибка сервера посмотрите логи апача.

Comment: @binliz Обновил вопрос

Comment: Такое впечатление что выливали вы на сервер по ftp и файл ваш не залился полностью. А по поводу вывода ошибок, если вы php.ini поправили а php как модуль апача то вам надо перегружать апач

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну проблема похоже с версиями PHP. Убедитесь что стоит версия не ниже той, которая поддерживает то что называют "мягкий type hinting". Это 7.1 насколько я помню . Ну и вот тут посмотрите

[тот же вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901247/after-upgrate-to-laravel-5-6-i-have-error-php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpe)

Решают проблему удалением версии 7.0

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.0 php7.0-common
```

Так же надо убедиться что апач использует требуемый модуль интерпретатора.

Comment: "Так же надо убедиться что апач использует требуемый модуль интерпретатора." А как в этом убедится? И если апач использует не этот модуль, как исправить?

Comment: Наберите в консоли `php -v` посмотрите какая версия php
Что касается апача, я больше с nginx дружу, тем не менее беглое гугленье подсказывает что в убунте можно посмотреть список модулей 
`apache2ctl -M` соответственно включение - выключение модулей происходят по команде `a2enmod` `a2dismod`